# how to copy selected rows from one wpf datagrid to another wpf datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

**Copy rows from one WPF datagrid1 to another wpf datagrid2**

I want to copy selected rows from wpf one datagrid1 to another wpf datagrid2.
[In uploded image i done this concept in window form applliction.
But now i want it in wpf window.

[image]

As show in image first select checkbox for different records from datagrid1 which want to copy and then on copy button copy selected rows in another datagrid2 with one additional column Quantity .in quantity coloumn then i am adding new value manually

Comment: my reply in xml: `<question quality='gimme teh codez'><actions><donvote/><votetoclose/></actions></question>`

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Please consult http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

with WPF you should remove the SelectedItems from your first bound collection and add them to your second bound collection... check out MVVM, ObservableCollection, ICommand, Binding, DataContext

EDIT:
just from my mind

viewmodel

```
public ObservableCollection<MyEntity> MySelectionCollection {get;set;}
public ObservableCollection<MyEntity> MyQuantityCollection {get;set;}
public DelegateCommand<IList> MyAddCommand {get;set;}


private void MyAddCommandExecute(IList items)
{
  //remove from MySelectionCollection 
  //add to MyQuantityCollection 
}
```

view

```
<DataGrid x:Name="SelectionGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MySelectionCollection }"/>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyQuantityCollection }"/>


<Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding MyAddCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=SelectionGrid,Path=SelectedItems}"/>
```

Comment: How dare you to reply without full xml and C# code? :-)